# send a post request to Splunk API server with Cloudflare Access using Golang's net/http package

Tags: go, cloudflare, splunk

I'm trying to send a POST request to the Splunk API server using Golang's net/http package. The request works fine with Postman, where I provide the CF-Access-Client-Id and CF-Access-Client-Secret as headers, and username and password for basic authentication. However, when I use the following script, it returns an error and the body of the response is very large and strange:

```
client := &http.Client{
    Timeout: 30 * time.Second,
}

data, err := json.Marshal(map[string]string{"search": "| tstats count where index=syn_epintel sourcetype=GraphSecurityAlert by sourcetype | fields count"})
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Errorf("unable to marshal the query %v", err))
}

request, err := http.NewRequest(
    "POST",
    "https://my.splunk.com/services/search/v2/jobs",
    bytes.NewBuffer(data),
)
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Errorf("unable to create POST request to the event server %v", err))
}

request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
request.Header.Set("CF-Access-Client-Id", os.Getenv("CF_ACCESS_CLIENT_ID"))
request.Header.Set("CF-Access-Client-Secret", os.Getenv("CF_ACCESS_CLIENT_SECRET"))
request.SetBasicAuth(os.Getenv("SPLUNK_USERNAME"), os.Getenv("SPLUNK_PASSWORD"))
r, err := client.Do(request)
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Errorf("unable to execute POST request to the event server: %v", err))
}

var sid string

body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
if err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Errorf("unable to read the response body: %v", err))
}

if err := xml.Unmarshal(body, &sid); err != nil {
    panic(fmt.Errorf("unable to unmarshal the response body:%v", err))
}
```

The error message doesn't provide any helpful information. How can I fix this? What could be causing the response body to be so large and strange?

Comment: Please share the response.  It may not be helpful to you, but might help someone else understand the problem you're having.

Comment: And share the error message too. And maybe the `Content-Type` header is incorrect because the request body is a json: `request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")`.